# how to navigate to a jsp page from a jsf page or managed bean

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces

I need to navigate to jsp page from another jsf page with the action of p:commandButton.

This is for jsf 2.2, primefaces 6.1, java 7. I have tried different options from managed bean:

`return "/Reportes/generaReporte.jsp"`

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/Reportes/generaReporte.jsp")`

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "/Reportes/generaReporte.jsp")`

But none has worked. Also I tried with the onsuccess property of p:commandButton:

```
onsuccess="#{generaReportes.trimestre ne '' ? window.open('{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/Reportes/generaReporte.jsp') : false}"
```

p:commandButton properties are:

```
value="Genera reporte PDF" 
actionListener="{generaReportes.doGeneraReporte}" 
type="submit" ajax="false" 
action="#{generaReportes.abrirReporte}" 
rendered="#{generaReportes.reporteSeleccionado ge 1 and 
generaReportes.reporteSeleccionado le 6}"
```

Managed bean:

```
public String abrirReporte(){
    return "/Reportes/generaReporte.jsp";        
}
```

I am getting the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

Comment: learn about errors and stacktraces, most likely only jsp or only jsp related.

Comment: Meaning: you might get the same error directly loading the jsp without a redirect from jsf.